# Can I distribute SharePoint Framework extension with existing SharePoint Provider-Hosted Add-in?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, spfx

I've got new SharePoint Framework extension. Is it possible to distribute it with existing SharePoint Provider-Hosted Add-in? Or i need distribute it as new *.sppkg which client need upload to AppCatalog?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?